# Solidity's Keccak256 function requires mining?

Tags: solidity, remix, keccak

I have used keccak256 and passed 3 parameters. Does keccak256 require mining?

Comment: What do you mean by "require mining"? When executed from a transaction you need to mine it as usual. If you use call() (constant function), then you don't, as any other instruction.

Answer (score 2):

No, it just returns a value without changing the state stored on the blockchain. That means you can make a function that takes some parameters and returns a keccak256 hash, and call it without sending a transaction or waiting for anything to be mined.

As with any other function that you want to call in this way, you'll need to mark it `constant`.